# jQuery .get > append div to page

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, get, append, tumblr

I am trying to implement script which loads automatically all the content from tag in tumblr. Code looks like this:

```
if (is_int($("#page-count").text())) {totalPages = parseInt($("#page-count").text())};
for ( pageCount=2; pageCount<=totalPages;pageCount++) {
    $.get("/page/" + pageCount, function(data){$('#test').append($('data > #gallery')});

}
```

The problem is that I cannot select #gallery content using $('data > #gallery') (or at least, I am doing it completely wrong). Could somebody give me a hint on how to select it properly?

Comment: having the full data response will help, as Matt's answer seems correct. On a side note, numerical ids are invalid in html, and can cause pesky bugs.

Comment: no, I am not using numerical ids. When I send get request, I get regular html page. #gallery is nested somewhere in the body. Is there any way I can help you guys solve this problem? I really have no idea why it doesnt work

Comment: I tried document.write($('#gallery', data)); > It says it's an object

Comment: can you show your response json encoded string

Comment: tried it. it says "Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON". I tried Firefox and it will write object like this: {"length":0,"prevObject":{"0":{},"1":{},"2":{},"3":{},"4":{},"5":{},"6":{},"7":{},"8":{},"9":{},"10":{},"11":{},"12":{},"13":{},"14":{},"15":{},"16":{},"17":{},"18":{},"19":{},"20":{},"21":{},"22":{},"23":{},"24":{},"25":{},"26":{},"27":{},"28":{},"29":{},"30":{},"31":{},"32":{},"33":{},"34":{},"35":{},"36":{},"37":{},"38":{},"39":{},"40":{},"41":{},"42":{},"43":{},"44":{},"45":{},"46":{},"47":{},"48":{},"49":{},"50":{},"51":{},"length":52},"selector":"#gallery"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I didn't manage to use any of your answers, instead I found out that, if I add HTML comments before and after the content I want to use, I can do it like this:

```
for ( pageCount=2; pageCount<=totalPages;pageCount++) {
    $.get("page/" + pageCount, function(data){
        new_posts = data.split("<!-- posts-start --\>")[1].split("<!-- posts-end --\>")[0];
        $("#gallery").append(new_posts);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
$.get('/page/' + pageCount + ' #gallery', function(data){
    $('#test').append(data);
});
```

Note that there is a space between the url, e.g. `/page/1`, and ' #gallery'. This will instruct jQuery to search for `#gallery` inside the response, and not pass it as part of the url.

Comment: no it is not. But it doesnt really make any difference whethere you request page/2/ or page/2/#gallery since it is still same html object you get returned

Comment: It's not "page/2/#gallery", but "page/2/ #gallery" (with a space between url and #gallery). With this, jQuery automatically returns only the content of #gallery

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to select `#gallery` from a tag named `data`, which of course doesn't exist. Try this:

```
$.get("/page/" + pageCount, function(data){$('#test').append($('#gallery', data)});
```

Comment: this doesn't really work for me either. when I do function(data){$('#test').append(data)}, it will append the whole html fine, but when selecting only contents of div#gallery your way, it does nothing